# A SharePoint 2013 workflow in SharePoint Online doesn't complete

Tags: sharepoint, sharepoint-2013, sharepoint-online, sharepoint-workflow

I have SharePoint Online Site which was developed in SharePoint Designer 2013. It has a workflow that processes travel claims, The SharePoint Online List  exceeded its limit from 5000 and most of the workflows were suspended. Then I archived the SharePoint List, and made some space. But still the workflows are suspended and I get this Error
**System.ApplicationException: HTTP 500 {"error":{"code":"-2147024860, Microsoft.SharePoint.SPQueryThrottledException","message":{"lang":"en-US","value":"The attempted operation is prohibited because it exceeds the list view threshold.**

and the Workflow wont Start.

Some workflow have started but they are not moving further to next stage and when I checked, Got this Error

**Suspend this workflow
Activity in progress
Retrying last request. Next attempt scheduled after 7/24/2023 10:30 PM. Details of last request: HTTP InternalServerError to [https://XXXX.sharepoint.com/_api/web/lists(guid'20f89c6d-8d33-421f-9843-8c1ef03a2c3c')/Items?%24filt..](https://XXXX.sharepoint.com/_api/web/lists(guid%2720f89c6d-8d33-421f-9843-8c1ef03a2c3c%27)/Items?%24filt..). Correlation Id: c0c325d3-ca88-9231-a236-0095202216c6 Instance Id: 50a8606c-a8a5-4462-9c9d-e436a59a8219
The attempted operation is prohibited because it exceeds the list view threshold.
Retry now**

The List is Indexed and have 10 Indices out of 20. I the did one more thing, I made an new List and a new workflow (both having a new name) and moved a couple of Travel claims to that New List to test, and started the workflow, as long as the stage in first stage i.e. not acted upon by any one, the workflow is in the starting mode, it gives this message

[image]

But as soon as the first approval is received, it gives this message

[image]

Though the new list is far below the threshold limit

I need help to resolve this matter

Thanks